# I created pipeline , source is SAP HANA and Sink is Mongo Db. i want to truncate data from sink before inserting

Tags: azure-data-factory

Copy data from Sap HANA to Mongo DB . In that pipeline source is Sap HANA and Sink is Mongo DB. Before inserting into mongodb collection i wanted to truncate the sink data.

I tried with the lookup activity but it didn't work

If sink is sql then it provide options like pre copy script, stored procedure, and lookup.
but in my case sink is mongodb then in that case how to truncate the data before inserting

Comment: can you add what you tried and error you are facing

Comment: In Lookup  activity , mongo db is not supported. if sink is SQL then it has 3 methods i.e lookup, pre copy script and stored procedure . but my sink is mongodb. how to truncate the mongo db data

Answer (score 0):

As per the [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-mongodb?tabs=data-factory#supported-capabilities),

> Mongo DB is only supported in copy activity in ADF.

You can raise the feature request [here](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/forum/1219ec2d-6c26-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f032c) to add for the other activities like script and lookup.

As per the design of your pipeline, your requirement might not be possible only using ADF.
As a workaround, try to truncate the Mongo DB data using python or any other script.

Execute the script either by Azure function activity or Custom activity.

[image]

Add this activity before the copy activity so that it will truncate the data before the copy of data.